# When does pandas need to use .values to do manipulations?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where I need to do some simple calculations on particular data points. I was having a problem where the result was producing a `NaN` result.

In this simple version of what I was doing, the first attempt works fine, but the second produces a `NaN`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_data = {'Location' : ['Denver', 'Boulder', 'San Diego', 'Reno', 'Portland',
    'Eugene', 'San Francisco'], 'State' : ['co', 'co', 'ca', 'nv',
    'or', 'or', 'ca'], 'Rando_num': [18.134, 5, 34, 11, 72, 42, 9],
    'Other_num': [11, 26, 55, 134, 88, 4, 22]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = df_data)
df['Sum'] = np.nan

print(df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Denver', 'Rando_num'])
print(df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Denver', 'Other_num'])

#This works
df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Denver', 'Sum'] = (
        df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Denver', 'Rando_num'] +
        df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Denver', 'Other_num'])

print(df)

#This don't
df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Boulder', 'Sum'] = (
        df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Denver', 'Rando_num'] +
        df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Reno', 'Rando_num'])

print(df)
```

Using `df.loc` to find the specific data points works fine where location is Denver but not when it is two different locations. I don't get why that is. If I add `.values` it fixes the problem:

```
df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Boulder', 'Sum'] = (
        df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Denver', 'Rando_num'].values +
        df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Reno', 'Rando_num'].values)
```

Does the community know of cases where a function like this would need the `.values` element to work? Or put another way, what is fundamentally different once the `.values` is added?

If it helps, all elements are floats and the `df.loc` is always a single value.

Comment: The fundamental difference is that `.values` turns the Pandas DataFrame into a Numpy array.

Comment: Right, but why is that necessary in some cases and not others?

Comment: Do you have an example where it does not work? I have seen that but in general, it is related to problems with the index.

Comment: try `df['Sum'] = np.where(df['Location'].eq('Denver'), df['Rando_num'] + df['Other_num'], np.nan)`  You shouldn't need to use `.values`

Comment: @DanielMesejo, like the index has a dupe or some such?

Comment: Like pandas interprets that it must add the values where the indices match

Comment: @Vishnudev they are both floats, so that isn't the issue

Comment: Ideally, your first approach should have worked. As @DanielMesejo says, you'll need to specify the case where it doesn't work with a minimal example. I'm removing my previous comment to reduce irrelevant comments.

Comment: @DanielMesejo I figured out what is different. See the updated code above. The second summation fails.

Comment: @Vishnudev see new edit

Comment: @Tom Added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1st case**

```
df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Denver', 'Sum'] = (
        df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Denver', 'Rando_num'] +
        df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Denver', 'Other_num'])
```

Notice that the selection is same across and the indices remain the same. When you add values with same range of indices or size it works.

**2nd Case**

```
df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Boulder', 'Sum'] = (
        df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Denver', 'Rando_num'] +
        df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Reno', 'Rando_num'])
```

Here, the selections are different as given below and when you add `NaN` to a number, `NaN` is the result. Addition works at same index.

```
>>> df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Denver', 'Rando_num']
0    18.134
Name: Rando_num, dtype: float64

>>> df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Reno', 'Rando_num']
3    11.0
Name: Rando_num, dtype: float64
```

Additionally, to understand better

```
Left Index    Right Index    Sum
0->18.134     0->NaN         NaN
1->NaN        1->NaN         NaN
2->NaN        2->NaN         NaN
3->NaN        3->11.0        NaN
4->NaN        4->NaN         NaN
5->NaN        5->NaN         NaN
```

**3rd Case**

With `.values`

```
>>> a = df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Denver', 'Rando_num'].values
array([18.134])
>>> b = df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Reno', 'Rando_num'].values
array([11.])
>>> a + b
array([29.134])
```

Comment: So IOW, the `.values` bit solves the problem because pandas doesn't have an index to deal with anymore.

Comment: When you do `.values` it fetches the internal `numpy` array. Indexing is lost.

Comment: Yes we're saying the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI, After `.values` the addition has nothing to do with pandas. Now its numpy's play.